# Filter data.frame by a set of columns whose row values must be TRUE

Tags: r, filter

This is the MWE that reproduces my error:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  col2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
  col3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  col4 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
)

filterByTrueCols <- function(df, trueCols) {
  for (rule in trueCols) {
    df <- df[df[rule] == TRUE,]
  }
  df
}

filterByTrueCols(df, c("col1", "col2", "col4"))

>> Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

However, this modification solves my problem:

```
filterByTrueCols <- function(df, trueCols) {
  for (rule in trueCols) {
    # inserted to prevent error,
    # result should be the same since filtering makes sense only when there are rows
    if(nrow(df)) {
      df <- df[df[rule] == TRUE,]
    }
  }
  df
}
```

I know that asking multiple questions is not good practice, but in this case: Why does the error pop up and is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

**Edit**: In this case, the expected output is an empty data.frame since there is no row that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Accidentally had `tbl_df` in there. Removed in order to be free from `dplyr`, the error is still the same.

Comment: What is the expected output?  Please use an example that should return some output

Comment: See edit: empty `data.frame`

Comment: Perhaps you need `all(df[,1]==df[,2])` and use it with the `for` loop or using `combn` i.e. `combn(seq_len(ncol(df1)), 2, FUN = function(x) all(df[,x[1]] == df[,x[2]]))`

Comment: It's not clear what is your function supposed to do and in which case you won't get an empty data set. But it seems like your whole approach here could be summed up to some type a `rowSums` one-liner without a loop. Maybe `rowSums(df[c("col1", "col2", "col4")]) == 3`? Though I have no idea what your function does even.

Comment: The function is supposed to filter the dataset so that only those rows remain for which the values corresponding to the given column names are `TRUE`.

Comment: David, oh dear, how was I not able to see such a simple solution. Thank you :-)

Comment: Also try ```Reduce(`&`, df[c("col1", "col2", "col4")])```, this way you won't need to know the amount of selected columns.

Comment: If I write `rowSums(df[c("col1", "col2", "col4")]) == length(the column vector)`, I don't need to know either. But `reduce` is rather elegant, I agree.